# npm erased Plesk 12 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, unix, npm, plesk

My issue is pretty simple to explain and I guess hard to solve: I commited the stupidity of installing `npm` on a cloud based server with Ubuntu 16.04 with Plesk 12.

After reading [this article](http://sscnet.ch/content/install-nodejs-npm-less-ubuntu-plesk) I realized it was too late and after trying to connect to my Plesk GUI got an **403 error**.

Also if I execute `plesk` on the CLI, it shows:

```
user@server:~$ plesk repair
plesk: command not found
```

So, I erased Plesk... All my hosted sites on Plesk are reachable with their databases in their URLs or by SSH.

The hosting provider told me there is no way to restore Plesk without losing everything unless I made a backup, but I didn't. Maybe there is an alternative... Do you know it?

**Edit:** Content of `/var/lib/psa/dumps`:

> user@server:/var/lib/psa/dumps$ ls -lrta
>
> total 5708
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root     4096 ene  4  2017 ..
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   206315 ene  4  2017 mysql.preupgrade.12.0.18-12.0.18.20170104-173632.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     3417 ene  4  2017 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.0.18-12.0.18.20170104-173633.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   208481 ene  4  2017 mysql.preupgrade.12.0.18-12.5.30.20170104-174155.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     3002 ene  4  2017 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.0.18-12.5.30.20170104-174156.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   220725 ene 23  2017 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170123-062554.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     3002 ene 23  2017 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170123-062556.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   236736 feb  8 06:27 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170208-062713.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     3003 feb  8 06:27 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170208-062715.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   262580 feb 24 06:26 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170224-062621.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4603 feb 24 06:26 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170224-062623.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   258785 mar 22 06:26 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170322-062626.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4898 mar 22 06:26 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170322-062627.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   251339 abr 17 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170417-062540.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4899 abr 17 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170417-062543.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   244219 may 16 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170516-062533.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4373 may 16 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170516-062535.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   248044 jun  1 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170601-062529.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4381 jun  1 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170601-062530.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   273341 jul 17 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170717-062542.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root     4379 jul 17 06:25 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.12.5.30-12.5.30.20170717-062544.dump.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   367277 jul 20 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.8.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   367218 jul 21 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.7.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   368954 jul 22 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.6.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   369279 jul 23 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.5.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   368767 jul 24 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.4.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   369629 jul 25 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.3.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   370169 jul 26 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.2.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   368027 jul 27 06:25 mysql.daily.dump.1.gz
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root   368128 jul 28 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.0.gz
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 psaadm psaadm   4096 jul 29 01:32 .
>
> -rw------- 1 root   root       20 jul 29 01:32 mysql.plesk.core.prerm.12.5.30.20170729-013250.dump.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to change the hosting provider, as their answer is incorrect and it seems, that they don't have much experience with Plesk, nor do they seem to have much knowledge about Plesk.

Second, your statements are a bit unclear, as you state:

> although I made a backup

and directly afterwards you stated:

> and I didn't

Could you pls. clarify WHAT you did and what you forgot to do?

Third, pls. have a look at => "/var/lib/psa/dumps" and inform us about the possible content.

Fourth, if you have dumps located at "/var/lib/psa/dumps", you will always have the choice to re-install Plesk and to re-import the latest "psa", "mysql" and "horde" - databases from your dumps. How to restore a Plesk database dump is explained at:

=> https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213904125

If you have further Plesk related questions, I recommend a new thread at the official Plesk Community Forum ( => https://talk.plesk.com ) , where experienced Plesk users will help you with Plesk - related questions/issues/errors/problems! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have corrected those lines. I forgot to backup. I will look for those dumps.

Comment: I had to reinstall the server.